# To display current arp in second level of network

Tags: networking, mac, router, ip, arp

My Windows PC is connected to a router (192.168.1.1) and that router is connected to another router (192.168.2.1) like a child to it.

The nodes I wish to see in the ARP listing are connected directly to the second router (192.168.2.1). Like, the child router 192.168.1.1 has IP, 192.168.2.20, on the parent router, and I want to see MAC and IP of 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.19.

If I disconnect my PC from child router and connect it to the parent directly, the ARP command simply works fine and show the children of 192.168.2.1. But, what I want is to see the same, being a node under 192.168.1.1. So, is there a way to see the second level ARP listing?

Comment: Simply put, no. the arp listing is a list of all clients that are directly accessible, i.e don't need routing to another subnet.

Comment: Is there any other way possible? That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Put all the host in a single broadcast domain (all connected via one router), that's the only way. You could replace the second router with a switch to achieve this.

Comment: @mtak's solution would work, otherwise the router itself might give you this info, or you'd need a agent on the other network you can run the command on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARP is only relevant and only visible on the same local network segment. If you wish to see the ARP table on a device on another network segment you must ask that device.

In this case, either:

1. Log into the second router and have it show the list of hosts locally connected to that routers.
2. Or query that router in another way (e.g. with remote network management software).

Alternative are rebuilding your network so that everything is one big network segment. Which is often a bad idea. But technically it is a working third option.